# how to update laravel cache (redis driver) with paginate after delete or update a row

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

I want to cache all users with pagination and update cache after any changes on user table. this is my method. i will be glad anyone help me.

```
public function GetAll()
{
    $page = request()->page;
    $users = Cache::remember('users'.$page, 600, function () {
        return User::paginate(12);
    });

    return response()->json(['success' => $users], 200);
}
```

Comment: And what problem are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using [Cache Tags](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache#cache-tags). So tag every users page with 'users' tag, and then clear all cached entries on user update. For example:

```
$users = Cache::tags(['users'])->remember('users'.$page, 600, function () {
        return User::paginate(12);
    });
```

And then on update

```
Cache::tags(['users'])->flush();
```

Hope this helps.